# Is there any way to use a strftime-like function for dates before 1900 in php?

Tags: php

With all the thingies like %W
(excuse my php illiterateness im asking for a friend.)
Basically we need to replace strftime in a big obscure project with something without the 1970, or what is it, limit. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at PHP's [datetime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) which works with a 64-bit date/time value, so a much wider range of dates... enough to satisfy anybody except (perhaps) a paleobiologist

Pay particular attention to ediathome's createFromFormat() function in the comments on that page if you're looking specifically for an strftime() replacement

Comment: DateTime can go back 292 billion years in the past. That would not only satisfy paleobiologists but Big Bang theorists too! http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/intro.datetime.php